# nHibernate Restrictions Contains

Tags: nhibernate

I have a evaluate expression like mentioned below

Restrictions.In(criteriaItem.PropertyName,criteriaItem.FilterValues);

Restrictions.Like(criteriaItem.PropertyName,criteriaItem.FilterValues);

i want Contains how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

string.Contains would map to like in sql, just with added wildcards. Try:

```
Restrictions.Like(criteriaItem.PropertyName,"%" + criteriaItem.ContainsValue + "%");
```